# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error while accessing BOSH in openfire

Tags: openfire, strophe

i am using `http-bind` with openfire to enable `BOSH` and accessing that service using `strophe` and the issue is i am getting following error in chrome

here is the error in console

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://127.0.0.1/http-bind`. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin `'http://localhost'` is therefore not allowed access.

[image]

here is the request

[image]

i have enabled `BOSH` as follows in openfire

[image]

i have tried following to do in `apache` config file `httpd.conf` BUT NO EFFECT

```
<Proxy /http-bind>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /http-bind http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind
ProxyPassReverse /http-bind http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` indicates that you are making a [Cross-domain (CORS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) request and the necessary CORS headers are not available.

You are making a cross-domain request because the BOSH service (i.e. `http-bind`) is being served on a different port than your website.

I see in your HTTP Bind settings for OpenFire that you have enabled CORS. Perhaps you are using a Browser that doesn't support CORS? (Like IE9).

In any case, you can solve this for all browsers by instead of using CORS, reverse proxying the `http-bind` address to be on the same domain and port as from which the HTML is served.

This snippet in Apache will do that for you: (I'm assuming you're serving the site on port 80).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/http-bind(.*) http://localhost:7070/http-bind$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

So you can then access the BOSH service (i.e. `http-bind`) on the same domain (and port) as the site itself.

For more info, see [Converse.js documentation on this](http://conversejs.org/docs/html/index.html#overcoming-cross-domain-request-restrictions)